# Irreducibility of monomial ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

So far, I have encountered two notions of irreducibility for ideals:

1. We say that an ideal $I$ in a commutative ring $R$ is irreducible if it cannot be expressed as an intersection of two strictly bigger ideals, that is, if there are no ideals $J,K$ such that $I=J\cap K$, with $I\subsetneq J$ and $I\subsetneq K$.
2. When $I$ is a monomial ideal in a polynomial ring, we say that $I$ is irreducible if it can't be expressed as an intersection of two strictly bigger *monomial* ideals.

Are thes two definitions equivalent for a monomial ideal $I$? Clearly 1 implies 2, but I'm not sure about the converse.

Comment: What is a monomial ideal?

Comment: It is an ideal in a polynomial ring which is generated by monomials

Comment: Here are some observations:
i) Reducible monomial ideals can be expressed as the intersection of strictly bigger ideals that are not monomials ideals, e.g. $(xy,xz) = (x) \cap (y+z,xy)$ or $(xy,xz,y^2,yz) = (x+y,xy,yz) \cap (y+z,xy,yz)$.

Comment: ii) Given a reduction $I = J \cap K$ of type 1, replacing $J,K$ by their maximal monomial subideals $J′,K′$ doesn't necessarily give a reduction of type 2, e.g. $(xy,xz) = (x) \cap (y+z,xy)$ but $K′ = (xy,xz) = I$.
iii) Replacing $J,K$ by their "leading monomial ideals" $J′,K′$ also doesn't necessarily give a reduction of type 2, e.g. $(xy,yz,x^2z,xz^2) = (x,yz) \cap (xy,xz+y,yz)$ but $I \subsetneq (xy,xz,yz) = J′ \cap K′$. Here, given an ideal $J$, its associated "leading monomial ideal" is the ideal generated by the leading monomials of elements of $J$.